# Format the section heading

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox, section-titles

I would like to have the section headings formatted as follows (Please note the top-right corner is curved):

[image: Desired output]

I tried many things like :
 (1) using a tcolorbox - In this case, I cannot shift the left edge beyond my text. What I am getting is only like this:
[image]

(2) using overpic : to place an image below the text. But I am unable to adjust the image with the length of the text.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be a start.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpagenodes}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\definecolor{myblue}{RGB}{91,134,199}

\titleformat{\section}{}{}{0em}{%
\tikz[baseline={(sec-\number\value{section}.base)},myblue,remember picture]{
\node(sec-\number\value{section}) {\LARGE\bfseries\sffamily\MakeUppercase{#1}};
\fill[overlay] let \p1=($(sec-\number\value{section}.north)-(sec-\number\value{section}.south)$)
 in ([yshift=3pt]sec-\number\value{section}.south east) -- 
 ([yshift=3pt]sec-\number\value{section}.south-|current page text area.east)
 arc[start angle=0,end angle=90,radius=\y1-6pt] -| cycle;
}}

\begin{document}

\section{Introduction}

Pft pft.

\section{Another section}

Pft pft pft.
\end{document}
```

[image]